# Scala Eclipse IDE suddenly ignoring breakpoints

Tags: debugging, scala, eclipse-plugin, breakpoints

I've been using Scala 2.8RC1 and Scala Eclipse plugin for 2.8 RC1 happily for a few days.  However, last night  after adding a couple jar files to my environment (apache http client jars) the debugger just stopped stopping at breakpoints in scala code.

Java code stops fine at breakpoints.  I tried creating a new mimimal scala app breakpoints don't stop.  I've tried switching to sun-jre-1.6.0.20 from the openjdk-1.6.18 I had been using. I've switched to the scala 2.8 nightly and also eclipse plugin for scala nightly builds.  No luck.

I would greatly appreciate ideas for fixes.  Rather frustrating as the initial experience with 2.8 was really great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets/2731-breakpoints-against-objects-in-default-package-are-not-honoured

Says that scala eclipse plugin doesn't stop at breakpoints if you're class is in the default package (no package)

Adding a package and moving my class to it - make the debugger start working again.

Comment: Just to note that this has now been fixed.

Comment: If this was fixed, it's made a comeback. Sept 2014 and I just encountered this issue, and my Scala IDE is a fresh download

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that you've discovered a bug in the Scala tooling for Eclipse. The best place to take the issue is the scala-ide-user list here,

http://groups.google.com/group/scala-ide-user

If you're already sure that you've found a bug you can find instructions for opening a ticket here,

http://scala-ide.assembla.com/wiki/show/scala-ide/Bug_Reporting

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered this problem. Code is not in default package. I'm getting a warning about missing line numbers, but apparently that bug has been fixed and I can ignore the warning, per https://scala-ide-portfolio.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets/1000155-its-impossible-to-add-line-numbers-debug-info-to-compiled-project#/activity/ticket:

It did seem to stop at breakpoints in the main file, though.

Comment: call it an ide, if you insist